# Update on button click

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, button, sql-update

I have a button , the code is ok , but there's an error when updating.

this is the code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
   conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
   conn.Open();

   SqlCommand cmdC = conn.CreateCommand();
   cmdC.CommandText = "Update ComDet set cDetails = " + lblcDetails.Text + ", cDetails2 = '" + lblcDetails2.Text + "', PhoneNumber = '" + lblPhoneNumber.Text + "', PersonCharge = '" + lblPersonInCharge.Text + "' Where cName = '" + lblcNameP.Text + "'";
   cmdC.ExecuteNonQuery();
   MessageBox.Show("Data Updated");

}
```

and this is the error..

[image: error]

link to the error for bigger picture : [Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vClqg.png)

the form looks like this :

[image: Form]

in my mind right now , the error might be the spaces in the textbox.. but i dont know if it is.

can anyone point me where did i do wrong?

Comment: do not use concatenated query strings, learn how to create [parameterized queries](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/652238-parameterized-queries-sqlcommand)

Comment: @ManishMishra - ah , i know how to do that , but i'm lazy to do it , since my presentation is this friday , and this is the fastest way i could code..

Comment: "Update ComDet set cDetails = '" + lblcDetails.Text + "', cDetails2 = '" + lblcDetails2.Text + "', PhoneNumber = '" + lblPhoneNumber.Text + "', PersonCharge = '" + lblPersonInCharge.Text + "' Where cName = '" + lblcNameP.Text + "'";

Comment: @PranavSingh - yep , i was missing a single quote.. thank you for pointing it out.. :)

Comment: You have set your Initial Catalog to master, I think you must set it to appropriate DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PLEASE** Don't use string concatenations in your sql commands. You can be missing some quotes and it is hard to find where it is. Use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

Also this kind of concatenation are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
SqlCommand cmdC = conn.CreateCommand();
cmdC.CommandText = "Update ComDet set cDetails = @cDetails , cDetails2 = @cDetails2, PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber, PersonCharge = @PersonCharge  Where cName = @cName";
cmdC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cDetails", lblcDetails.Text);
cmdC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cDetails2", lblcDetails2.Text);
cmdC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", lblPhoneNumber.Text);
cmdC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonCharge  ", lblPersonInCharge.Text);
cmdC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cName", lblcDetails.Text);
cmdC.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: u meant something like this right? `daS.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = lblcNameP.Text;`

Comment: yep , i could do that... but i am in a rush.. heh.. will change it in a minute.. thank you again.. :)

the code works fine , i was missing a single quote on cDetails.. :)

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin I updated my answer as a full code. Take a look.

Comment: oh , i changed it like that aswell.. :) thank you... i know how to do parameters , but i didnt do it in this form yet.. thank you again.. :)

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin You are quite welcome. If one of these answers solve your problem, please consider to accept one. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

change Initial catalog.put ypur table name

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Datbasename;Integrated Security=True";
```

Try like this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstDetail",textbox1.text);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondDetail", Textbox2.Text);
```

[refer here](http://mrbool.com/inserting-data-into-sql-server-database-using-csharp-and-asp-net/25091)

Comment: The initial catalog is not the table name: Initial catalog is the database name.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid syntax error use formatted string as

```
cmdC.CommandText =string.Format("Update ComDet set cDetails = '{0}',cDetails2 ='{1}',PhoneNumber = '{2}',PersonCharge = '{3}' Where cName = '{4}'", lblcDetails.Text, lblcDetails2.Text , lblPhoneNumber.Text , lblPersonInCharge.Text , lblcNameP.Text );
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess two things are not correct:

on your data source, the initial catalog refers to the name of your database. You have "master". Should be like:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=yourDBname;Integrated Security=True";
```

Also, you are lacking quotes (and their order isn't always right) on your SQL statement, it should be:

```
cmdC.CommandText = "Update ComDet set cDetails = '" + lblcDetails.Text + "', cDetails2 = '" + lblcDetails2.Text + "', PhoneNumber = '" + lblPhoneNumber.Text + "', PersonCharge = '" + lblPersonInCharge.Text + "' Where cName = '" + lblcNameP.Text + "'";
```